# Testing with Spock - use a complex data provider

Tags: java, groovy, spock

Spock can run parametrized tests using the [Data Pipes](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/data_driven_testing.html) construct:

```
...
where:
a << [1, 7, 0]
```

It's very convenient for lists of values or one-liners that generate some custom list (e.g. `a << (0..9).collect({it*it})` But what's a convenient, readable way of providing a complex generated list as a parameter? A list that can't be easily generated in a single line of code.

**Edit:**
I realize that I use a separate static method to initiate the list, but that feels hackish, and I'm wondering whether there is a way of generating the parameters somewhere within the test itself. The `where` clause itself doesn't allow anything of that sort.

Comment: You mean to say that `a << (0..9).collect({it*it})` is not working?

Comment: It's working. But I want a more complex list, one that's harder to generate in a single line.

Comment: Such as? example would help better understanding.

Comment: Sure. Here are a couple of examples: 1. A list of variations on the string `abcd` with a single whitespace inserted in every possible position (e.g. `a bcd`, `ab cd`, `abc d`). 2. A list of all printable ASCII characters, with the exception of digits and lower case letters.

Comment: These are possible to create in a single line, but the result isn't very readable. Also, I can think of much more complex examples..

Comment: @Malt without your actual code it is hard to suggest a solution, just note that Spock can use anything that implements `Iterable` as a DataProvider. You can also use a static function that returns an `Iterable`

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Using a static method is nice and simple. It's the cleanest option so far. I was just hoping to find a more Spock-y way of doing that as part of the test- like some DSL that would allow for a generation of parameters within a test whereas the `where` clause allows only for one-liners.

Comment: @Malt as I said without the actual code it is hard to tell how you can do it nicely, but the `where` block doesn't require that the code is on one line.

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean complex list as list of objects, you can always break the objects to the relevant fields you are using in the test.

For example:
If you need a list of students, each student has the following data:

```
class Student {
    String name
    String lastname
    Int age
    String id
}
```

In the test you can build each object by divide it to its fields. 
So use the **where** section like that:

```
  where:
    name    | lastname | age | id
    "Ron"   | "Black"  | 34  | "2345"
    "Tom"   | "White"  | 26  | "8765"
```

Using that syntax enable you to have different object in every iteration, as defined in the where section.

I hope that is what you are looking for, because your question can be understood in different ways.

Comment: That's not really what I meant, although it's a nice example. I was talking about a list of simple types that's hard to generate in a single line.

Comment: Did you tried to run a function in the where block? for example running a private method that generate 5 random strings , so each iteration you will have different string? using the function enables you to use it in 1 line.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, using a static function. But I was hoping for a more Spock-y DSL for that sort of thing. `where` doesn't seem to allow anything of that sort.